# Paste column values of a list of matrices to another list of matrices

Tags: r, matrix, paste

I have a list of shapefiles. Here is an example of one of the shapefiles.

`ID Area_ORG LU_1990 LU_2000 CHLU_90_00 LU_2005 CHLU_00_05     Tile       UNIQ_ID      AREA D_90_00
0   597    27.27      11      11       1111       0       1112 S01_E031  S01_E031_597  274408.8     100
1   622    24.75      11      11       1111       0       1112 S01_E031  S01_E031_622  249063.6     100
2   816     8.97      11      11       1111       0       1112 S01_E031  S01_E031_816   90260.9     100
3   818    20.94      11      11       1111       0       1112 S01_E031  S01_E031_818  210709.6     100
4   886    25.92      11      11       1111       0       1112 S01_E031  S01_E031_886  260828.1     100
5   898   102.33      11      11       1111       0       1112 S01_E031  S01_E031_898 1029736.2     100
6   935    41.13      11      11       1111       0       1112 S01_E031  S01_E031_935  413891.1     100
7  1139    27.09      11      11       1111       0       1130 S01_E031 S01_E031_1139  272603.0     100
8  1169    22.95      11      11       1111       0       1112 S01_E031 S01_E031_1169  230945.5     100
9  1192    44.91      11      11       1111       0       1112 S01_E031 S01_E031_1192  451941.1     100
10 1196    26.91      11      11       1111       0       1112 S01_E031 S01_E031_1196  270798.2     100
11 1203    27.72      11      11       1111       0       1112 S01_E031 S01_E031_1203  278951.3     100
12 1244    38.61      11      11       1111       0       1112 S01_E031 S01_E031_1244  388546.4     100
13 1435    10.44      11      11       1111       0       1130 S01_E031 S01_E031_1435  105058.9     100
14 1436    24.75      11      12       1112       0       1230 S01_E031 S01_E031_1436  249060.9     520
15 1437    18.63      11      12       1112       0       1230 S01_E031 S01_E031_1437  187476.3     520`

Each shapefile has a Tile column. In this case, the tile column is in the column 8> But sometimes it is in other column. So I want to write the table by using the Tile name. I tried this code below but it does not work.

`for (i in 1:length(list_shp_Tanzania)){
  write.csv(list_shp_Tanzania[[i]], file = paste(list_shp_Tanzania[[i]]@data$Tile, "csv", sep = "."), sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)
}`

Comment: Ok, I see. Could you tell whether both these are lists or just one? If so, do they have the same length?

Comment: I am sorry, I was only looking at the data and thought it as just a matrix not a list of matrices.

Comment: Try `Map(function(x,y,z) {x[z] <- y[z];x}, list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod, LU_Mod2000, columnsToTransfer1)` (not tested)

Comment: Let me create some example data as your data is difficult to process.  Please use `dput` to show the data.

Comment: Here, I am getting the expected result using the example data I created

Comment: `lenM <- rbind(sapply(LU_Mod2000, nrow),  sapply(list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod, nrow)); rowSums(t(lenM)==lenM[1,])==2`

Comment: Hmm, then it seems unusual to get that error.  Can you also check whether these 61 matrices of each list have the `columnsToTransfer1`

Comment: `sapply(list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod, function(x) x[,columnsToTransfer1])` check if you get 61 columns

Comment: Could you be able to share the datasets in dropbox or some other link to have a look it

Comment: `2` in the other matrix means what?  Is it 2 rows ?

Comment: You can use `match` to get the indexes.  But, if there are two matrices with the same number of rows, it becomes tricky.  Do you have any other source to identify the matching elements of each list.

Comment: Check if this have anything to do with creation of `LU_Mod2000` especially the `which.max`?

Comment: Yes they have the same prefixes.

Comment: I think the issue does not come from the LU_Mod2000 because the order of the matrix matches well with the order of the shapefiles. It is in the other matrix that the order is messed up.

Comment: I understand the issue I think. In the write.table step, I named the file according to the row 1 and column 8 which is supposed to be the name of a tile. However, it seems that in some of the shapefiled, the name of the tile is not in column 8 but in another one. That is why the order is messed up. Do you how I can write my table with the name of the column instead of the number of the column? The column name is Tile. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Without the data, I am not sure how I can comment on it.

Comment: I showed u an example of how a shapefile looks like in the question. Maybe it helps.

Comment: I assume the shape files have different structure.  If I just copy, paste and build a data.frame, it won't be the same.  I would suggest you to dput subset of rows/columns of the list.

Comment: Ok. I managed to get the same list of matrices strucutre.

Comment: Check the `str()` of the shapefile, and show the output.

Comment: It seems that ur `Map` solution is working.  I will try to do it with the other list of matrix I ahve to use to keep updating the list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod list of matrices. The same procedure should be working, right?

Comment: Yes, it should work if the corresponding elements are matching.

Comment: I get this error message `Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , z, value = c(14, 14)) : subscript out of bounds`. I guesss there is something wrong again with my datasets.

Comment: If the columnsToTransfer1 is not present one of the list, the error can occur. In the example I showed. change `list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod[[2]] <- list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod[[2]][,-1]` and then run the `Map(..)` you will find the same error.

Comment: In that case, create an indx to weed out those doesn't have the columns `indx <- sapply(list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod, function(x) any(colnames(x)==columnsToTransfer1))` and the same can be done with `LU_Mod2000`.`indx1 <- sapply(LU_Mod2000, function(x) colnames(x)==columnsToTransfer1); indx2 <- indx & indx1` and then do `Map(function(x,y,z) {x[,z] <- y[,z];x}, list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod[indx2], LU_Mod2000[indx2], columnsToTransfer1)`

Comment: I realized that the datasets I got are a bit messed up. Again, some of the shapefiles are missing some columns which have to be filled by LU_2000/LU_2005 matrices. That is why I have some errors.

Comment: This work but I want all my matrices to have the same strucutre at the end. The list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod matrices are matrix which have been done by using another approach. That is why, in some cases, information are sometimes missing such LU_2005 and so on. But For my study I have all this information. Therefore, I think I have to create 61 new matrices with all the columns I need and update it with list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod, LU_2000, LU_2005 matrices, and so on. Would you know How I can create this list of new matrices corresponding to the structure of 61 matrices created before?

Comment: For the ones without the columns, do you want to keep it that way?

Comment: No. I want all the new 61 matrices to have all the columns including the missing ones. Basically, the number of row in each matrix has to stay the same but in some matrices some columns would be added.

Comment: I edited the post. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
res <-  Map(function(x,y,z) {x[,z] <- y[,z];x},
               list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod, LU_Mod2000, columnsToTransfer1)

sapply(res, function(x) x[,"A"])[1:3,] #changed list matrix
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   19   10   19   15
#[2,]   19   15    3   17
#[3,]    6   19   20    8

sapply(list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod, function(x) x[,"A"])[1:3,] #original list matrix
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   15   24   27   47
#[2,]   12   19    7   26
#[3,]   36   14   26   33

sapply(LU_Mod2000, function(x) x[,"A"])[1:3,] #second list matrix `A` columns
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   19   10   19   15
#[2,]   19   15    3   17
#[3,]    6   19   20    8
```

#### Update

If there are cases where the `columnsToTransfer1` is not found in some of the list elements of either one of the lists. For example, by removing the column of interest in the 2nd element of `list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod`

```
 list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod[[2]] <- list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod[[2]][,-1]
  Map(function(x,y,z) {x[,z] <- y[,z];x},
             list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod, LU_Mod2000, columnsToTransfer1)
  #Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , z, value = c(10L, 15L, 19L, 6L, 10L, 19L, 20L,  : 
  #subscript out of bounds
```

You can correct it by subsetting the lists that have the column for all the corresponding elements

```
   indx <- sapply(list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod, function(x) 
                      any(colnames(x)==columnsToTransfer1))
 
   indx1 <- sapply(LU_Mod2000, function(x) any(colnames(x)==columnsToTransfer1)) 
   indx2 <- indx1&indx
   res <- list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod
   res[indx2] <- Map(function(x,y,z) {x[,z] <- y[,z];x},
        list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod[indx2], LU_Mod2000[indx2], columnsToTransfer1)
```

#### data

```
columnsToTransfer1 <- "A"
set.seed(24)
list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod <- lapply(1:4, function(i) matrix(sample(1:50, 4*10,
              replace=TRUE), ncol=4, dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:4])))

set.seed(42)
LU_Mod2000 <- lapply(1:4, function(i) matrix(sample(1:20,10, replace=TRUE),
       ncol=1, dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1])))
```

Comment: I got these error message. `Error in x[, z] <- y[, z] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Comment: @Simon Besnard Do you have the dimension i.e. rows for each of the corresponding matrices of each list same? You mentioned these have the same lengths ie. 61.